# How to use UITextFields?

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I'm doing the following in my App right now:

```
NSInteger myReell1 = 6;
NSInteger myReell2 = 7;
NSInteger myImag1  = -5;
NSInteger myImag2  = 3

+ (WSData *)scientificData 
{

float dataSet2D[2] = {0,myReell1 + myReell2};
float dataSet3D[2] = {0,myImag1 + myImag2};

return [WSData dataWithValues:[WSData arrayWithFloat:dataSet2D len:2]
                      valuesX:[WSData arrayWithFloat:dataSet3D len:2]];

}
```

This worked fine for me up to now.
Here is what I would like to change and what I would like to ask you for:

I would like to use 4 `UITextFields` to give the opportunity of personal input to the user, instead of the consistent Integers (myReell1, … ,myImag2) which I use right now.

How would you implement those `UITextfields` (maybe just 1 example?) into the code above to make the `NSInteger` part needless.

Please don't mind about the actual stuff inside of the scientific data. ;-)

Comment: you mean yo want to get input from user to assign to your integer value define above???

Comment: @ParasJoshi: your answer was basically what I was looking for, but did not answer the question which I was having. My problem is doing what David Haynes suggested in his first and second statement :)

Comment: okay, after reading about and playing around with textfields I got it now... thank all of you for your support!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presuming this code is inside a view controller, you can:

1. Create your UITextField member variables in the class.
2. Subscribe the class to UITextFieldDelegate.
3. Wire your text fields up in Interface Builder (or instantiate them programatically and add them to the view).
4. Implement the didFinishEditing delegate method to handle the
   actual    input.

Comment: See CBredlow's answer for an example of how to do number 4 on my list.

Comment: Thank you :)
Could you give me a small example/hint on how to create the member variables in a class and subscribe it to the UITextfieldDelegate?

Answer (score 0):

Say you make 4 textfield boxes, you can get the integer from going 
    myReell1 = [textFieldOne.text intValue];

and so on, there you have an integer you can use constantly, with no hardcoding

Answer (score 0):

First put Textfield and then when user click some button just put bellow code in you button click metho...

```
NSInteger myReell1 = [textField1.text intValue];
NSInteger myReell2 = [textField2.text intValue];
NSInteger myImag1  = [textField3.text intValue];
NSInteger myImag2  = [textField4.text intValue];
```

:)